# PHP MySQLi How to show user profile image in html table?

Tags: php, html, image, mysqli

I'm trying to show the profile image of the user in HTML table where i list the rest of user's info. But i can't get it to show, instead i'm getting [Broken Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juq89.png) in the table. And if i right click on the "broken image" and choose "Open image in new tab" i can see the path of the image and the link to the image [Parent Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF5uW.png)
I'm uploading the the path of the image to the database and storing the image to a folder ( images/profilepic ).

Can someone help me please? Thanks a lot!

This is my insert.php code:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "employees";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$profile_file = basename($_FILES['profileimg']['name']);
$profile_path = "images/profilepic/$profile_file";
$profile_file = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $profile_file);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimg']['tmp_name'], $profile_path);


$sql = "INSERT INTO addemployees (profileimg)
        VALUES ('$profile_file')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  header("location: employees.php");

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

//Close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

And this is where i'm showing it:

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
                             <thead>
                               <tr class="naslov">
                                   <th class="th-sm">ID:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm">Profile Picture:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm">First Name:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm">Last Name:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm">DOB:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm">EMBG:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm">Work Position:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm">Address:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm">Contract:</th>
                                   <th class="th-sm" colspan="2">Опции:</th>
                               </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody id="myTable">

                          <?php

                              $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "employees");

                            if (!$conn) {
                            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                            }

                              $sql = "SELECT * from addemployees";
                              $result = $conn-> query($sql);

                              if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
                             while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {




                               echo "<tr>
                                      <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                                      <td><img src='images/profilepic/'". $row['profileimg'] ."' border=0 class='tile' id='profileimg'></td>
                                      <td>".$row['fname']."</td>
                                      <td>".$row['lname']."</td>
                                      <td>".$row['dob']."</td>
                                      <td>".$row['embg']."</td>
                                      <td>".$row['workposition']."</td>
                                      <td>".$row['address']."</td>
</tr>";


                          }

                            echo "</table>";
                          }
                            else {
                            echo "0 results";
                          }

                        $conn-> close();

                              ?>

                              </tbody>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting. Plus, what was stored as an image in the row, a filename or as a BLOB?

Comment: i'm storing a filename

Comment: check your path for it then; error reporting will tell you if it isn't right.

Comment: You could also have permissions errors on the directory.

Comment: also, the corresponding image for it should reside in the same folder, not just the filename. Letter case could also be at play here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  The path seems to be okay since it is storing the image file in the folder and the path to the database. I'm using the same for uploading/storing/showing PDF documents and that works fine. But i have no idea why it won't show the image. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way i'm trying to show?

Comment: The values in the database look fine. The storing path is okay i think. See the [database](https://i.imgur.com/MTTUTRf.png)

Yes the value is what i expect in the HTML but not expecting broken image :) @miken32

Comment: View your browser source code and check the value in the image src if it is what it should be

Comment: @miken32 i just checked the path and it looks fine. Please see the [ScreenShot](https://i.imgur.com/asucH7d.png). Thanks

Comment: Yup, just noticed I was misreading your storage code. Typo in the answers is almost certainly your issue.

Comment: Also note you should not rely on DOM inspector to look at your HTML. View source instead.

Comment: You do plan on using a prepared statement (open to sql injection), if and when you go online with this, right? Otherwise, you might find your database deleted one day.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes of course :) i'm planing on working on the already done code at the end of the week. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quote **before** the variable in your `<img src`:

```
<td><img src='images/profilepic/". $row['profileimg'] ."'
                                ^-- remove the ' here   ^-- but leave this one
```

The way you have it now, your variable is outside the `src` attribute:

```
// if $row['profileimg'] is image.jpg:
<img src='images/profilepic/'". $row['profileimg'] ."' border=0>

// will become:
<img src='images/profilepic/'image.jpg' border=0>
//                          ^-- end of the src='' argument
```

Comment: Thanks rickdenhaan. That made the path as it should. But i'm still getting the "broken image"

Comment: @Blagojce Is the display code in your question still current? In the screenshot you posted, there is an extra `'` at the very end of the `src` which shouldn't be there.

Comment: rickdenhaan great eye :) Thank you very much i didn't spot that. That `'` was making all the trouble :) Thanks again.